# How to fill (wrap) an org mode heading?

Tags: org-mode, fill-paragraph

I would like to fill (wrap) a long heading in org mode. I don't see mention of how to do so in the [org manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/index.html).

If I manually wrap the line by inserting a newline, org mode does not recognize the wrapped text as a heading.

Is this possible?

Note: `org-fill-paragraph` does not do this:

```
(defun org-fill-paragraph (&optional justify)
  "Fill element at point, when applicable.

This function only applies to comment blocks, comments, example
blocks and paragraphs.  Also, as a special case, re-align table
when point is at one.

If JUSTIFY is non-nil (interactively, with prefix argument),
justify as well.  If `sentence-end-double-space' is non-nil, then
period followed by one space does not end a sentence, so don't
break a line there.  The variable `fill-column' controls the
width for filling.

For convenience, when point is at a plain list, an item or
a footnote definition, try to fill the first paragraph within."
  (interactive)
  ; ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original poster is using the words `fill` and `wrap` interchangeably -- they are *not* the same.

See the variable `org-startup-truncated`:

```
Non-nil means entering Org-mode will set `truncate-lines'.
This is useful since some lines containing links can be very long and
uninteresting.  Also tables look terrible when wrapped.
```

The default is `t`.  To change this, the user can put the following code into the `.emacs` file:

```
(setq org-startup-truncated nil)
```

`org-mode` needs a line-end to correctly identify a heading.  To see an example of the regexp that `org-mode` uses for headings, the user can type (after an `org-mode` buffer has been loaded):

`M-x describe-variable RET org-complex-heading-regexp RET`

As can be seen, the ending is `$` -- i.e., to the end of the line.

```
^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(TODO\\|DONE\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(\\[#.\\]\\)\\)?\\(?: +\\(.*?\\)\\)??\\(?:[     ]+\\(:[[:alnum:]_@#%:]+:\\)\\)?[    ]*$
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying filling vs. wrapping. That distinction is not clear from reading www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillParagraph. Thanks for showing the underlying regular expression. As for take-aways, is this accurate?: Unless one modifies that regex, filling (inserting newlines) is not an option. Truncation will work, either using the way you show or with `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` (shown in my answer).

Comment: To disable truncation automatically, the variable `org-startup-truncated` is most appropriate because the initialization of `org-mode` checks the value of that variable and unless it is `nil`, the initialization process specifically sets `(setq truncate-lines t)`.  To keep the default behavior and only toggle it manually, then `toggle-truncate-lines` is certainly appropriate.  The underlying regex for headlings cannot be easily changed (in my opinion) because there are a million and one functions that rely on it -- e.g., `org-agenda-list`; `org-search-view`; `org-tags-view`, to name a few.

Comment: You may also be interested in `visual-line-mode` which endeavors to keep whole words together when wrapping.  For my own setup, I have modified the editing of todo entries as follows:  editing automatically narrows the buffer to the task I'm editing; `visual-line-mode` is activated and I do my editing; when exiting the narrowed buffer, `visual-line-mode` is turned off; truncation remains the default when the buffer is *not* narrowed.  I have a custom setup that keeps the un-narrowed buffer in a read-only state, which is made readable when editing, and then set to read-only when done.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how to make filling work. So a work-around is to use `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`. This only affects the presentation of the heading. It does not insert newlines.